# Disable heroku from redeploying review app on every push to a github pull request

Tags: git, github, heroku, continuous-integration, heroku-review-app

I have a github repo linked to a heroku pipeline and currently heroku has an automatic behavior of recreating the review app on every push to a PR. We have our own code that handles the review app creation and redeployment so we want to disable this automatic behavior.

The below support article from heroku discusses an issue where a review app is being recreated instead of doing a redeployment, but we want to disable both recreation and redeployment.

https://help.heroku.com/YCFHG3X6/why-is-my-review-app-being-recreated-on-every-push-to-the-github-pull-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from Heroku support that there is a GUI setting for this under the review app "Deploy" tab:
[image]

However currently the only way to disable this setting is through the GUI. I requested that heroku support open enhancement requests for the following:

- Provide an api for disabling auto-deploy on a review app.
- Provide a pipeline level setting that determines the default value of
  auto-deploy for new review apps that get created.